# Angular build warning "Bundle initial exceeded maximum budget." I know how to remove the warning, but how big is too big?

Tags: angular, filesize

I am creating a small HTML game (think Wordle). There are only a few small pages (home/game/about/create). I don't use many, but I do have Angular Material controls package installed. I'm shocked that such a tiny app is exceeding the standard limits. But I'm also quite unsure how large is too large, or how to reduce the size?

I know I can go into angular.json and set the budgets, so my question is really more about WHAT to set them to, and WHY. Are the initial budget values just too small to begin with? My app currently peaks around 1mb after prod build with --aot. It seems to run fine. I'm just curious if there is a rule of thumb about file sizes?

Comment: In short, it doesn't matter. Set it to the maximum size that provides acceptable network performance for your target audience. If you don't have metrics for that, then it _really_ doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

You can update your maximum allowed budget for production in your [angular.json](https://github.com/Fleker/pokemon-as-a-service/blob/main/client/angular.json) file.

If it is too big consider looking at the libraries you're using and if they're necessary. Note that the bigger your website is, the longer it may take for someone to load it.

```
...
"configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2000kb",
                  "maximumError": "5600kb"
                },
...
```

Comment: Thanks Nick. However, as I mentioned, I know HOW to change it, my question is WHAT to change it to? Or more specifically, how big is too big? How do I determine the answer to that question?

Comment: Those kinds of questions are not objective. In my case, I've set the budget to just under 6MB. In the error message you should see your app's current size. Consider doing a bit of math based on your average customer. If they're on a slow 28KBps connection, it could take over a minute for them to load my site, but a person on a 5G connection wouldn't have the same latency. If your app has analytics you might be able to see what sizes would be acceptable, but smaller is always better.